# Partition over Vec<Result<T, E>> fails due to type mismatch

Tags: rust

I'm attempting to collect a series of calculations which can fail into two vectors, one containing the successful calculations and one containing any errors.

I can instantiate the vector Vec<Result<T, E>> but calling partition fails to compile.

Example code:

```
fn main() {
    let f:Result<i32, String> = Err("a".to_owned());
    let s:Result<i32, String> = Ok(5);
    let v:Vec<Result<i32, String>> = vec![f, s];
    
    // works
    dbg!(&v[0]);
    dbg!(&v[1]);
    
    // fails
    let (sp, fp):(Vec<_>, Vec<_>) = v.iter().partition(Result::is_ok);
    dbg!(sp);
    dbg!(fp);
}
```

Error below:

```
error[E0631]: type mismatch in function arguments
  --> src/main.rs:12:56
   |
12 |     let (sp, fp):(Vec<_>, Vec<_>) = v.iter().partition(Result::is_ok);
   |                                              --------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                                              |         |
   |                                              |         expected signature of `for<'r> fn(&'r &Result<i32, String>) -> _`
   |                                              |         found signature of `for<'r> fn(&'r Result<_, _>) -> _`
   |                                              required by a bound introduced by this call
```

Based on the rust by example docs this seems like it should be doable - what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iter()` returns an iterator over references, and `partition()` takes a callback that takes a reference - that's two references. `Result::is_ok()`, however, takes `&self` with one reference.

You can either use `into_iter()` or provide a closure that takes two references: `.partition(|result| result.is_ok())`.